# I'm confused about ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate and possibly concurrency. Why is there a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My confusion starts with this snippet from [the api description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) for the method scheduleAtFixedRate.

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

If there will be no concurrent execution, why is there a Thread pool?

Also, is there a way to get concurrent execution?  I want them running at the exact period even if the prior task hasn't finished yet.  I want concurrent execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation should be read as:

> ..subsequent executions [of the supplied Runnable task, per registration] .. will not concurrently execute

This does not mean that there will not *no* concurrency over all scheduled tasks. Rather, for each task (created by invocation of `scheduleAtFixedRate`), the Runnable only executes on one thread at a time - *even* if the execution time overruns the interval.

This is an explicit design choice, as in most situations concurrent execution of task callbacks is undesirable and leads to out-of-control resource spirals. For instance, a "task bomb" could form if an increasing number of (the same) Runnables were executed concurrently.

The Thread Pool monikor is accurate as the implementation does what it is advertised to do - reuse threads across the execution of tasks.

---

While there is no standard [Thread Pool] Executor that will have the requested behavior it can be emulated in a limited fashion. This is because the concurrency restriction is per-task that is registered (not per-Runnable) and multiple 'identical' tasks can be registered:

```
long targetPeriod = ..;
long n = targetPeriod * 2;
task1 = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, n, ..)
task2 = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, n/2, n, ..)
```

The actual execution/timing behavior depends on various other factors, but both of these registered tasks *could* execute concurrently if they take over ~n/2 (the target period) to execute.

Comment: Ah.  I think I get it.  So, I can start many Runnables running using the same executor.  The different Runnables can all be running concurrently if I've supplied enough Threads.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Dale Yes, that's correct. You could even supply the same Runnable multiple times, each time it is supplied it is effectively creating a different task, which is able to run concurrently with the others, given available threads etc. If this was done and the tasks were scheduled to run a N rate (but be offset by N/2) then it is possible that they run 'interleaved' and stacked wrt. eachother (being different registered tasks, that run the same Runnable).

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to get concurrent execution? I want them running at the exact period even if the prior task hasn't finished yet. I want concurrent execution.

You could launch another thread for (or submit to another executor) the actual task from the scheduled task (assuming the rate is long enough to launch a thread or submit the task). If the task consistently takes longer than the rate you want you may eventually run out of resources (as described in the other answer).

For example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        new Thread(() -> {
            //do task
        }).start();
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```